# Share simple content on Facebook time line

Tags: javascript, html

I want to share some simple text content on facebook time line using javascript of html. I have tried the below but i am unable to add any content, Can anyone help me how to create the below url to share content dynamically. What is the key for sharing content.

[facebookshare](http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D=Title&p%5Bsummary%5D=Testasdfasfasdfasdf%20Summary.&p%5Burl%5D=http://www.ideocentro.com/)

Thanks
djrecker

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the url shared, i.e. if you are using PHP try to call

```
p[url]=urlencode(LINK)
```

Same to the title and summary